# How to convert a list of tuples to individual lists

Tags: list, tuples, python-3.3

I want to convert this list of tuples:

```
            [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50),
             ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60),
             ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22), 
             ('ANZ', 'Anzbankgrp', 26.25),
             ('ARG', 'Argosy', 12.22),
             ('CEN', 'Contact', 11.22),
             ('CNU', 'Chorus',3.01),
             ('DIL', 'Diligent', 5.3),
             ('DNZ', 'Dnz Property', 2.33),
             ('EBO', 'Ebos', 1.1),
             ('FBU', 'Fletbuild', 3.2),
             ('FPH', 'Fisherhealth', 16.12),
             ('FRE', 'Freightway', 6.71),
             ('FSF', 'Fonterra', 9.93),
             ('GMT', 'Goodmanprop', 3.52),
             ('GPG', 'Guinnesspeat', 2.32),
             ('HLG', 'Halglass', 0.2)]
```

Into individual lists. For example [AIA, Auckair, 1.5] and [AIR, Airnz, 5.60] and so on.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your original list of tuples is stored in arr. Then

```
newArr = []
for a in arr:
    a = [j for j in a]
    newArr.append(a)
```

This should make newArr a list of lists. So instead of  [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50), ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60), ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22)... ] you would have [['AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50], ['AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60], ['AMP', 'Amp',3.22]... ]

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also what code would I need to write for it to point to third object in every list? For example a code that would return all the floats in the entire list.

Comment: @user2101517: it would be floats = [] ; for a in arr: floats.append(a[2])

Comment: `[j for j in a]` can simply be written `list(a)`.